# Meteor 0.6.6.1 - Login with Twitter - auth callback issue

Tags: authentication, twitter, meteor, callback

I am setting up a Meteor app with Twitter login and ran into following problem: I would like to make my local development version of the app accessible for my colleagues (at http://server.mydomain.com:3000), but the Twitter login callback always redirects to localhost:3000. I am perfectly able to log in, but my colleagues aren't.

Unfortunately I didn't find any reference on how to define the callback url within Meteor's login service configuration:

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "twitter",
  consumerKey: "***",
  secret: "***"
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you set twitter's callback url to `server.mydomain.com:3000/_oauth/twitter?close`. The setting would be in twitter at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/

The second thing is to make sure you're running your app in deploy mode as opposed to development mode where you also have to set your `ROOT_URL` environmental variable to `http://server.mydomain.com:3000`.

Comment: Cheers! I forgot to set the ROOT_URL. With a simple  `export ROOT_URL=http://server.mydomain.com:3000` in the app folder, everything worked like a charm.