# Meteor accounts-twitter unable to get working

Tags: twitter, meteor, oauth, cloud9-ide, meteor-accounts

I've been having a go at Meteor. I want to use OAuth to authenticate users on my site as I do not want to implement the login features myself.

At the moment my website is very simple. A counter, where you click a button the counter increases by one. The idea being when a user goes to another machine and logs in their count is persisted.

I have followed the steps on [meteor.com/accounts](https://www.meteor.com/accounts).

1. `meteor add accounts-twitter` and `meteor add accounts-ui`
2. Added `{{> loginButtons}}` to HTML.
3. In Cloud9 terminal `meteor --port $IP:$PORT`
4. Followed the on screen instructions on [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com/)
5. Set website `abc-matthewcanty.c9.io/`
6. Set callback URL `http://0.0.0.0:8080/_oauth/twitter` - this is what I am told to do.
7. Copied in `API Key` and `API Secret`
8. Chose pop-up based authentication and pressed save

Now when I click *Sign in with Twitter* I get a pop up which says:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

The address of the popup is as follows:

> 0.0.0.0:8080/_oauth/twitter/?requestTokenAndRedirect=true&state=eyJsb2dpblN......

**Note** that using `abc-matthewcanty.c9.io/` as the Callback URL makes not difference.

Is this because I am using [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/matthewcanty) and there is a little more tinkering that I have to do?

The Meteor documentation provides no further steps. Probably assumes knowledge of OAuth as a prerequisite but does not state as such.

**Edit**

I visited the site suggested by @tomas-hromnik below:

http://www.servicepro.wiki/wiki/1171/cloud9-twitter-account-integration-for-sign-up

And updated the app settings in apps.twitter.com:

- Website: https://abc-matthewcanty.c9.io/
- Callback URL: https://abc-matthewcanty.c9.io/ also tried this with *_oauth/twitter?close*

When I click on the button I don't know how to stop it from going to *http://0.0.0.0:8080/etc*

[image: Twitter OAuth naviating to 0.0.0.0]

Comment: Is your workspace / application server access public? You can check that by clicking on 'Share' and seeing whether 'Public' is checked next to 'Application'

Comment: Sorry still nothing... Updated addresses to the public facing application URLs. Tried regenerating app key & secret and reconfiguring.

Comment: If I take the URL that is in the popup window and add my website in place of the IP:PORT then the authentication completes.

Comment: Hmm, so, this is just a guess, but its possible that meteor package hard-codes 0.0.0.0:8080 in the callback url and twitter respects it. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363677/meteor-0-6-6-1-login-with-twitter-auth-callback-issue) maybe helps, set the ROOT_URL env variable to your workspace url.

Comment: :-D Works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome! :) I'll post that as an answer to help others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83769/discussion-between-bassbytesbikes-and-mutahhir).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to do to make Twitter auth work with Meteor on Cloud9:

- Make sure your application is Public, not private. You can do that by clicking on 'Share', and checking Public next to 'Application' within your Cloud9 workspace
- Make sure you set the twitter callback as `https://<workspace-name>-<username>.c9users.io`
- Since Meteor twitter auth package defaults to using `0.0.0.0:8080` (the IP:PORT you start it with) as the callback host, so you need to add the `ROOT_URL` environment variable. If you're using a Cloud9 runner, you can add environment variables by clicking on the 'ENV' button on the run panel and adding it. Set ROOT_URL to your application's external URL. Otherwise you can just do it within the terminal by typing in: `$ export ROOT_URL='https://<workspace-name>-<username>.c9users.io/'`

*Note:* Please note that by default Meteor starts at port 3000, but you need to set the port to 8080 in order to make it work.

Comment: You can also set environment variable in the terminal: `$ export ROOT_URL='https://abc-matthewcanty.c9.io/'`

Comment: Yes, I just added the Cloud9 runner way since people usually know about export, but this. I'll add this too :)

Comment: This also solved my similar problem for OAUTH and accounts-google on Cloud 9, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the address 0.0.0.0:8080 is correct. Meteor runs on port 3000 by default and his address is localhost, so the callback URL should be http://127.0.0.1:3000/_oauth/twitter?close

Read more about using Twitter login with Meteor in this tutorial: http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/login-with-facebook-twitter-and-google-in-meteor

**EDIT**: For production usage use your production URL:

```
http://abc.matthewcanty.c9.io/_oauth/twitter?close
```

Here are steps for creating Twitter account integration on Cloud9: http://www.servicepro.wiki/wiki/1171/cloud9-twitter-account-integration-for-sign-up

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible in Cloud9. The terminal requests that you execute `meteor` with the argument `--port $IP:$PORT`. Which sets you up on 0.0.0.0 port 8080.

Comment: To add to that, I tried running Meteor without any arguments and it isn't possible to reach the page in Cloud9 - ie, by browsing to localhost:3000 in the embedded browser.

Comment: If you add production URL and allow the twitter app to be used to sign in with Twitter, it must work. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Updated my question with further information. Please note it should have been *abc-* not *abc.*