# OAuth using meteor in Cloud 9

Tags: meteor, oauth, uri, cloud9-ide, facebook-oauth

I am trying to sign users into my application using an external app. In this case, facebook. I am using cloud 9, so I don't have the meteor app(ide) downloaded on my pc. Anytime I try to use facebooks activation, i get this error:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

I already created my app on facebook. The uri uses: http://0.0.0.0:8080
That's not what I set it to use on facebook. Any pointers on fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. You can export your app so that it runs on the right url you want it to.

Command: $ export ROOT_URL='https://-.c9.io/'

This gets rid of 0.0.8080 or whatever.

Check this question for reference: [Meteor accounts-twitter unable to get working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503844/meteor-accounts-twitter-unable-to-get-working)

Comment: This also solved my similar problem for OAUTH and accounts-google on Cloud 9