# Meteor auth Twitter callback option

Tags: twitter, callback

Setting the callback URL for Meteor Twitter auth. I have searched widely and all options I've tried end with a 'Internal server error' error message on the login page.

I currently have:

`"ROOT_URL": "https://mydomain.org.uk",`

...though I have also tried options such as: "localhost:8080", "localhost", "https://mydomain.org.uk", "https://crew.streetscenes.org.uk/_oauth/twitter?close", "https://crew.streetscenes.org.uk/_oauth/twitter" and others.

In the Twitter config setting I have tried everything, "http://127.0.0.1", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/_oauth/twitter" and various other

[Meteor 0.6.6.1 - Login with Twitter - auth callback issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363677/meteor-0-6-6-1-login-with-twitter-auth-callback-issue)

server.mydomain.com:3000/_oauth/twitter?close

I also tried with "Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)` checked.

Comment: Hello, have you been able to solve this problem?  I am going threw something that is a bit similar; at least from the callback port standpoint, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061898/how-to-force-twitter-single-sign-on-to-use-https-on-port-443).  I am trying to make the callback use a specific port.

Comment: No, was too much trouble. Gave up on Twitter auth for the time being..

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer.  Thanks.