# How to force Twitter Single Sign-On to use https on port 443

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ssl, twitter

I have set up an rails application that uses Twitter for single sign-on.

In my twitter configurations, my call back looks like the following:
`https://somesite.com/users/auth/twitter`

But the redirect code from `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=someoauthtoken` has the following code in the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://somesite:80/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=someoauthtoken&oauth_verifier=someoauthverifier”>
```

How do I force Twitter Single Sign-On to use https on port 443?

I tried changing the callback setting in my twitter account to `https://somesite.com:443/users/auth/twitter` but it still uses port 80 on the redirect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

Does anyone have a Ruby on Rails application using https with a twitter callback? Are you not suppose to use https if you are using twitter for single sign on?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone going through this problem, here is what solve the problem form me.

I added some middleware that just changes the server port to 443

```
env['SERVER_PORT'] = '443' unless env['SERVER_PORT'] == '443'
```

Somewhere on the web server I am using, `env['SERVER_PORT']` was set to 80.  Twitter was using this value on the callback.

There is probably a web server setting that can be changed, but I do not have access to make that change, so this will have to do.

Hope this helps someone.